# Making a div inside a bootstrap col full height and putting buttons at the bottom of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this template of code here and I want to make the panel in the center column full height of the visible page. Keyword 'visible' page. And then I want to place the button at the bottom of that panel, while the rest of the panels elements are at the top.

I tried setting the div to 'height: 100vh' but it makes the div higher then the visible page. I'm not sure why, maybe it has something to do with the navbar at the top?

The desired effect is that I will always see the button at the bottom of the page, regardless of the page size.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Messages</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 well">
        <div class="well">
          <p><a href="#">My Profile</a>
          </p>
          <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <p><a href="#">Interests</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="label label-default">News</span>
            <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
            <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
            <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
            <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
            <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
          <p><strong>Ey!</strong>
          </p>
          People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
        </div>
        <p><a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default text-left" style="height:100vh">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 well">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
          <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
          <p><strong>Paris</strong>
          </p>
          <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <p>ADS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <p>ADS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which button and which div?

Comment: the div that contains the panel that is in the 'col-sm-7' column. It's the center panel on the page. It has the 'Like' button

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as you already said, the navbar is the "problem" here.

If you try to subtract the navbar height from the desired height of the panel it should work:

```
element.style {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```